# Application Insight errors and exceptions dosn't end up in Failures

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

I have migrated from a regular Azure function app in azure to AKS.
I have added the Instrumentation Key to our manifest/helm charts.
And i can also see requests logs and errors in the Transaction search and Performance tabs, but the errors and exception that is getting logged dosn't end up in the "Failures" tab.

Has anyone had the same problem or what could be the problem?
I'm glad for any help.
Cheers.

[image]

host.json file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host": "Error",
      "Function": "Error",
      "Host.Results": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Error"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Exception"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried changing the host.json file to many different settings, but I really don't think that's the problem.

Edit: I compared the new app insight I set up against the one that was set up against our regular azure function app. The new app insight seems to be connected with log analytics, could this be the problem?

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya C# .NET

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

**`host.json`:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**`Function1.cs`**

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {

            _logger.LogError(new Exception("something wrong"), "TestLog ErrorWithException");


            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

- check the exceptions from here in Application Insights:

[image]

Comment: Is this running in AKS?

Comment: Its running in Azure Container.